# compare in javascript innerHTML and value

Tags: javascript

I need to compare the javascript condition below : but I get only false
How can I fix that ?

```
if(document.getElementById('captchaTypedValue').innerHTML == String(document.getElementById('login:inputCodSeg').value))
```

returns me false

`captchaTypedValue` is `span` element
`login:inputCodSeg` is `input` element

javascript chromium console

[image]

Comment: Hard to say. Did you tried using `console.log` for each value before the condition ?

Comment: first of all you're missing two )

Comment: Do you really have an id that is `login:inputCodSeg`, and does the value match the HTML, and if so why ?

Comment: I have a login popup and need to compare the typedvalue with the genereated captcha

Comment: I would probably trim just to be sure....

Comment: also, you're missing at least one parenthesis in your if clause

Comment: Now do what DontVoteMeDown has suggested, what you see?

Comment: it seems to me that the code in the image is not equal to the one in the description..

Comment: Use this instead `console.log(document.getElementById('captchaTypedValue').innerHTML);` and `console.log(document.getElementById('login:inputCodSeg').value);`.

Comment: Ive used alert(.... and both two values are equals at least for to my eyes

Comment: Then log the `.length` of those values too.

Comment: thats right  String(document.getElementById('captchaTypedValue').innerText.length)
"4"
document.getElementById('login:inputCodSeg').value.length
4 only for testing but the condition does not match

Comment: now it works with innerText == value  if(String(document.getElementById('captchaTypedValue').innerText) != String(document.getElementById('login:inputCodSeg').value)) thanks :)

Comment: Notice, that `innerText` is somewhat IE-only, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) is a standard property. Notice, that possible white-spaces and line-breaks _in the file_  have influence to the returned value.

Comment: thanks for the important tip @Teemu. I will test with textContent

Comment: You might also want to trim the value from the input. If you accidentally hit space after the text in the input the values will also return not equal.

Comment: that is the intention when using captcha. You need to pay attention when typing the right value. thx

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
if(document.getElementById('captchaTypedValue').innerHTML == String(document.getElementById('inputCodSeg').value)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

basically I think you don't have an ID called `login:inputCodSeg`. If that doesn't work, it's probably because the condition simply is not true.

ALSO:

if you would like to use jquery:

```
if ( $('#captchaTypedValue').html() == $('#inputCodSeg').val() ){  
   // do stuff    
}
```

should work

EDIT: there's also a chance that the condition is just not true

Comment: Please don't post [Not enough jQuery answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question), dude.